# Is it a way to stop printing AmqpRejectAndDontRequeueException stacktrace logs in spring boot?

Tags: java, spring-boot, exception, rabbitmq

I am trying to setup dead-letter-queue in spring boot app but when I am throwing  `AmqpRejectAndDontRequeueException`, it's print whole stack trace in the console which I don't want.
Is there any better way to do it?

I have tried to catch that exception but after that dead-letter-queue stopped working.

```
2019-06-25 17:26:33.221  WARN 19812 --- [ntContainer#0-1] s.a.r.l.ConditionalRejectingErrorHandler : Execution of Rabbit message listener failed.

org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.exception.ListenerExecutionFailedException: Listener method 'public void com.example.consumer.Consumer.process(com.example.consumer.api.PaymentOrder)' threw exception
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.adapter.MessagingMessageListenerAdapter.invokeHandler(MessagingMessageListenerAdapter.java:198) ~[spring-rabbit-2.1.6.RELEASE.jar:2.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.adapter.MessagingMessageListenerAdapter.onMessage(MessagingMessageListenerAdapter.java:127) ~[spring-rabbit-2.1.6.RELEASE.jar:2.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.doInvokeListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:1552) ~[spring-rabbit-2.1.6.RELEASE.jar:2.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.actualInvokeListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:1478) ~[spring-rabbit-2.1.6.RELEASE.jar:2.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.invokeListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:1466) ~[spring-rabbit-2.1.6.RELEASE.jar:2.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.doExecuteListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:1461) ~[spring-rabbit-2.1.6.RELEASE.jar:2.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.executeListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:1410) ~[spring-rabbit-2.1.6.RELEASE.jar:2.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer.doReceiveAndExecute(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:870) [spring-rabbit-2.1.6.RELEASE.jar:2.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer.receiveAndExecute(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:854) [spring-rabbit-2.1.6.RELEASE.jar:2.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer.access$1600(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:78) [spring-rabbit-2.1.6.RELEASE.jar:2.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer$AsyncMessageProcessingConsumer.mainLoop(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:1137) [spring-rabbit-2.1.6.RELEASE.jar:2.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer$AsyncMessageProcessingConsumer.run(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:1043) [spring-rabbit-2.1.6.RELEASE.jar:2.1.6.RELEASE]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [na:1.8.0_144]
Caused by: com.example.consumer.InsufficientFundsException: insufficient funds on account XK45 0654 5271 7424 1755
    at com.example.consumer.Consumer.process(Consumer.java:28) ~[classes/:na]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_144]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_144]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_144]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_144]
    at org.springframework.messaging.handler.invocation.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:171) ~[spring-messaging-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar:5.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.messaging.handler.invocation.InvocableHandlerMethod.invoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:120) ~[spring-messaging-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar:5.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.adapter.HandlerAdapter.invoke(HandlerAdapter.java:49) ~[spring-rabbit-2.1.6.RELEASE.jar:2.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.adapter.MessagingMessageListenerAdapter.invokeHandler(MessagingMessageListenerAdapter.java:190) ~[spring-rabbit-2.1.6.RELEASE.jar:2.1.6.RELEASE]
    ... 12 common frames omitted
```

It should be on one line with one message of error description and dead-letter-queue should work.

Answer (score 0):

I just solved the same problem by having this in my application.yml file

```
logging:
  level:
    org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.ConditionalRejectingErrorHandler: OFF
```

If you are using application.properties file, you can have below line

```
logging.level.org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.ConditionalRejectingErrorHandler=OFF
```

Answer (score 0):

You should look at the logs and see what class is printing the exception. in your logs you can see that  org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.ConditionalRejectingErrorHandler is the source of the exception so like Rajesh mentionned above setin the logs to OFF should work. in my case I had to set org.springframework.integration.handler.LoggingHandler to OFF

```
logging.level:
    org.springframework.integration.handler.LoggingHandler: OFF
```